# Implementing Django Grappelli Dashboard

Tags: windows, django, dashboard, django-grappelli

I've happily implemented Grappelli for the first time. I was trying to implement the dashboard but it doesn't seem to be activating. Trouble is, I'm not sure what it looks like.

The Grappelli dashboard.py is applied (generated by createdashboard)

settings.py (interesting parts)

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'I:/xampp/htdocs/project/media'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://cdn.pd/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://cdn.project/'
GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_HEADLINE = 'Admin Headline'
GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'pd.dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard'
GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_URL = '/admin/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'I:/xampp/htdocs/pd/src/templates'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'grappelli.dashboard',
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
)
```

does anyone have any pointers? Heres a format of my project. Its empty aside from basic django initiation:

```
project  - pd
         |
         |- dashboard.py
         |- urls.py
         |- settings.py
```

Any pointers would be cool.

Comment: the dashboard.py must be located outside pd folder because your path is pd.dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little late for you.  You need also need to add     django.core.context_processors.request to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

settings.py will include:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.request"
```

)

Comment: I had done that yes. I just gave up on this. I've never used the dashboard. I think there is a conspiracy and it doesn't actually exist. But +1 for good advice. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you not customized templates/admin/index.html in your code.
I see that grapelli and grappelli.dashboard use different files,
but only when you use second one, your dashboard be visible.

Comment: indeed dashboard/template/admin/index.html needs to be used. Nice catch!